# I am getting a error during using apache derby

Tags: derby

[image]

This is my screen.

How can i resolve this problem or how i switch my valid java version. I installed java 8 and i did enter this command that "alternatives --set java java 8 path file". But he don't run.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Please don't post text as image.